# How to replace CRLF in a text string with <br> for use in HTML Email in Automate Flow

Tags: replace, format, field, html-email

I am trying to get a multiline rich text sharepoint field show up in it's formated value as seen in the SharePoint Column and in the variable flow controls. I have tried 5 options with exactly the same results in each and every test.

The value appears as this in SharePoint (multiline, rich text field):[Field with 2 lines of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Cst.png)

The results in the email are this (I used the field item first but during testing have been using the strMaterials and str MaterialsNew variables): Plant 2411 A\CP9314-CWR/B0 (No properly formated break code (br))

I have created the following flow (only relevant portion shown):[Material String Format flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OoOK.png)

Replace strings tried are:

1. replace(variables('strMaterials'),variables('strCRLF'),'break code') - strCRLF variable contains %0D%0A
2. replace(variables('strMaterials'),decodeURIComponent(variables('strCRLF')),'break code')
3. replace(variables('strMaterials'),'CRLF','break code')
4. replace(variables('strMaterials'),'\n','break code')
5. replace(variables('strMaterials'),decodeURIComponent(%0D%0),'break code')

Results are always the same:
[Email results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8p8w.png)

I just can't seem to find the answer to keep the formating of the column even though the email is in html mode:
[HTML mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0r2N.png)

Comment: I don't really know how it works but if it's HTML, wouldn't you replace it with `<br>`?

Comment: in the description I use 'break code' to represent the '<br>' because it would disappear in my strings when I posted this originally)